# Problem with Ruby mechanize and inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm working with mechanize and having problems with inheritance when testing in a rails environment, using script/console.

When I write like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.google.com'
```

Everything works fine. But when I try to create a subclass of WWW::Mechanize like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

class Alfa < WWW::Mechanize; end

agent = Alfa.new
agent.get 'http://www.google.com'
```

I get the following error:

NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.parse
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/page.rb:77:in `parser'

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you actually tried digging into mechanize source at the said page to see what's there?

Comment: Yes I've been looking at the code for some time but I'm guessing I have to do something extra about the subclass.

Comment: Have you tried to put your "Alfa" Class into the same namespace as Mechanize?

Comment: Do you mean: 

module WWW
class Alfa < Mechanize
end
end

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subclass WWW::Mechanize, no HTML parser is provided : that is what the error line actually tells you.

This works :

```
class Agent < WWW::Mechanize
end
a = Agent.new
a.html_parser = Nokogiri::HTML
a.get 'http://www.google.com'
```

Comment: Thanks i-blis, I thought these setup steps were made automatically by the underlying Page class.